# mouse.move tag not working for my autoclicker

Tags: python, pi

i am currently making an autoclicker script for an samsung galaxy A70 with my raspberry pi pico in micro-python.

```
This is my code:
import time
import usb_hid
from adafruit_hid.mouse import Mouse
import board
import digitalio

mouse = Mouse(usb_hid.devices)
led = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.GP25)
led.direction = digitalio.Direction.OUTPUT

led.value = False
time.sleep(25)
mouse.move(y=360)

while True:
        led.value = True
        mouse.click(mouse.LEFT_BUTTON)
        time.sleep(0.01)
```

The problem i currently have is that the mouse.move tag wont work, it keeps putting the cursor in the middle-bottom of my phone. i already tried using different values for the y coordinate but that doesnt seem to help it.
does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in **adafruit_hid.mouse** you have to Send USB HID reports before you use the  `LEFT_BUTTON`
so you have to put a variable at the start of your code like this

`LEFT_BUTTON = 1` for the LEFT MOUSE BUTTON

`RIGHT_BUTTON = 2` for the RIGHT MOUSE BUTTON

`MIDDLE_BUTTON = 4` for the MIDDLE MOUSE BUTTON

so your code will be like this:

```
import time
import usb_hid
from adafruit_hid.mouse import Mouse
import board
import digitalio

MIDDLE_BUTTON = 4
RIGHT_BUTTON = 2
LEFT_BUTTON = 1

mouse = Mouse(usb_hid.devices)
led = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.GP25)
led.direction = digitalio.Direction.OUTPUT

led.value = False
time.sleep(25)
mouse.move(y=360)

while True:
        led.value = True
        mouse.click(mouse.LEFT_BUTTON)
        time.sleep(0.01)
```

Comment: Awesome! i am new to learning python and this really helps me! Do u happen to know how to point the X and Y value to make the mouse.move go to the center of my screen?

Comment: sorry this is not a teaching platform! you can check the documentation! it has everything just google "adafruit_hid python documentation"

Comment: i appreciate that u mention it! i didnt knew what stack overflow really was. i fixed my own problem by googling stuff! have a nice day/night/morning bro!